# Read table from Hive without map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hcatalog

How to read from Hive without map reduce? I am trying to read a column from a table created on Hive, but I don't want the overhead that exist from map reduce. Basicaly I want to retrive the values from a table created on Hive without overhead and get them the fastest way possible.

Comment: Seems like http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz My problem is I want to read values from a table created on Hive without the overhead that exists on map reduce operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of MapReduce, you can use Tez or Spark as you execution engine in Hive.

See *hive.execution.engine* in [Hive Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties).

There are also quite a few SQL engines compatible with the hive metadata e.g Presto, Spark SQL, Impala.

Answer (score 0):

generally, if you do a "select *from" a table in hive mapreduce wont run..

In your case are you using just a select column from a hive table also mapreduce wont run.

or you can create a subtable on the main table with the needed columns and number of rows and just do a select * on the table.